# vba use cell data to check images on site for words that match and then download them

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, ocr, tesseract

excel cells have words in, it checks a given website for the words, screen prints the site and saves the screen print with the name of the word used, then inserts the webaddress in to the cell next to the used word and works down the sheet list until empty. what I want vba to do is use the open source ocr tesseract that I think this job will very much need.

so far I have managed to get words or car regs to be inserted in to a site and then extract the data, I don't know where to start with the above paragraphs project I have set my self.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'Sub TAXandMOTcheck()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer                'special object variable representing the IE browser

    'Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    'Dim liEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <li> (link) element
    'Dim pEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element

    Dim y As Integer                             'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    'Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'open internet

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'open tax/mot page

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/"

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'enter details in to page

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'in the search box put cell "b2" value, the word "in" and cell "C" value
    objIE.document.getElementById("Vrm").Value = _
                                               Sheets("INPUT DATA").Range("X3").Value

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'click the 'Continue' button
    objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'click the 'Yes' button
    objIE.document.getElementById("Correct_True").Click

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'click the 'Continue' button
    objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'TAX EXPIRY DATE:
    'TaxExpiryDate = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
    'add tax date to sheet
    'Range("G3").Value = TaxExpiryDate

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'IN TWO LINES FOR BETTER CODE READIBILITY:
    TaxExpiryDate = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
    TaxExpiryDate = Split(TaxExpiryDate, vbNewLine)(1)

    'add tax date to sheet
    Range("Y3").Value = TaxExpiryDate

    'IN ONE LINE FOR SHORTER CODE:
    'TaxExpiryDate = Split(objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText, vbNewLine)(1)
    'add tax date to sheet
    'Range("G3").Value = TaxExpiryDate

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'wait 5 seconds
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'MOT EXPIRY DATE:
    MotExpiryDate = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(1).innerText
    MotExpiryDate = Split(MotExpiryDate, vbNewLine)(1)

    'add mot date to sheet
    Range("Z3").Value = MotExpiryDate

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'take tax and mot dates and insert in to cells next to each other
    'the first search result will go in row 2
    y = 2

    'TAKE TAX EXPIRY DATE AND PUT IN CELL
    'I have tried reading up on extracting data from li elements, parent and child elements but struggling
    'For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")
    'data = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText

    'TAKE MOT EXPIRY DATE AND PUT IN CELL
    'I have tried reading up on extracting data from li elements, parent and child elements but struggling
    'For Each itemEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")
    'data = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
    y = y + 1

    'take next car reg and do the same as above until there are no cells in rows with a car reg
    'Next y

    'Range("A3").Value = data

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'close the browser
    objIE.Quit

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'exit our SearchBot subroutine and start new row for new website data
End Sub
```

Comment: I am a little unclear where you are stuck. Have you been using a specific OCR site? Or API?

Comment: hi Qharr, I hope you are well. sorry, it is ambiguous. if its ok I would like some time to get back to you. Gaz

Comment: What I found confusing was the mention of OCR. I understand the code from the perspective of returning tax etc info for a given input reg. Tessaract (certainly pytesseract and Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine) is for reading text from images and I was wondering how this, and the screenshots., fit with your workflow

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that in addition to what already had been achieved in the code, you may only require to save the screenshot of the site and loop through the number of car registration numbers (already listed in a excel sheet). Also could not understand and found commented out Class Id `("top-section-list")` in the specific site.

Since I don't have valid vehicle registration numbers of UK, I tried the code only with some imaginary number (luckily found in trial error) and repeated in a loop.The path,sheets and range etc may be modified to your requirement. The application wait time may be further reduced.

Modified Code:

```
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44
    Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
    Sub TAXandMOT()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim CarReg As String
    Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String
    Dim TaxExpiryDate, MotExpiryDate
    Dim Shp As Shape, Cht As Chart, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Path As String

    Path = "C:\users\user\Desktop\"
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Data")

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    y = 1
    CarReg = Ws.Range("A" & y).Value

        Do While CarReg <> ""
        objIE.navigate "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/"
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        objIE.document.getElementById("Vrm").Value = CarReg
        objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        objIE.document.getElementById("Correct_True").Click
        objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        TaxExpiryDate = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
        TaxExpiryDate = Split(TaxExpiryDate, vbNewLine)(1)
        Ws.Range("B" & y).Value = TaxExpiryDate
        MotExpiryDate = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("status-bar")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(1).innerText
        MotExpiryDate = Split(MotExpiryDate, vbNewLine)(1)
        Ws.Range("C" & y).Value = MotExpiryDate


        'SendKeys "(%{1068})"                  'another option to take screen Shot 
         ShowWindow objIE.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
         Delay 3
         Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
         Delay 1
        Set Cht = Charts.Add
        Cht.Paste
        Cht.Export FileName:=Path & CarReg & y & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG" ' may not use y (i have to use Y as I have only one car no to repeat for trial)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Cht.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        y = y + 1
        CarReg = Ws.Range("A" & y).Value
        Loop
    objIE.Quit
    End Sub

Sub Delay(Sec As Integer)
tm = Timer
    Do While Timer < tm + Sec
    DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Ahmed AU, thank you for your help, I cant seem to get this code to work and would very much like to keep the code I have written as that's all I know unfortunately, I can manage small snippet add ins but that's about it. Thank you for your time and have a good day. Gaz